# Optional equation break

Tags: equations, split

Is it possible to have optional breaks in equations, which are automatically decided at compile time depending on whether the linewidth is sufficient or not?

For instance, consider the following:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \mathtt{this\_is\_a\_long\_name}(arg_1, arg_2) = \mathtt{this\_is\_a\_long\_name}(arg_2, arg_1)
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

With `a4paper`, it's fine, there is no badbox: [image]

but if I switch to `a5paper`, the space is not sufficient anymore: 
[image]

so I'd like to split the equation, as using `split`, e.g.:
[image]

but only if it is required (i.e. not doing so would cause a `Overfull \hbox`). Is there any package to do so ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a job for the `dmath` environment of the `breqn` package. Examples on A4 and A5:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
\begin{dmath}
    \mathtt{this\_is\_a\_long\_name}(arg_1, arg_2) = \mathtt{this\_is\_a\_long\_name}(arg_2, arg_1)
\end{dmath}
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
\begin{dmath}
    \mathtt{this\_is\_a\_long\_name}(arg_1, arg_2) = \mathtt{this\_is\_a\_long\_name}(arg_2, arg_1)
\end{dmath}
\end{document}
```

[image]

So `breqn` takes care of automatically breaking the math lines in case they are longer than the available width.

Comment: Yep, that's it! However, I noticed there is a slight difference in the number positionning (in particular with `llncs` style), but this is for another question :-)

Comment: @Bromind Note that `breqn` has several bugs and might not be supported by journals.

Comment: Yes, I saw that in the doc. But for the moment, it seems to mostly work for me (at least, compilation terminates). I have to investigate further.